# Saving a backbone collection to MongoDB in express

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have looked around for tutorials on saving a collection to the backend but so far I have found none, what is the proper way of sending the collection to the server.

Looking at the documentation, it doesn't have a save method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [sync method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sync) in Collections.

> synccollection.sync(method, collection, [options])
>
> Uses Backbone.sync to persist the state of a collection to the server. Can be overridden for custom behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I did have a look at it and Using it now